# Plugins for Firefox and Chrome for switching context?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, productivity

I wuld like to have a plugin which would help me to change context I'm working with.

Suppose I have two tasks I'm working on and I want to easily retain and restore groups of open tabs.

Anyone knows such plugins?

Answer (score 1):

For firefox, this addon might be the answer: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/

I also found a similar one for chrome: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-manager/bbcnbpafconjjigibnhbfmmgdbbkcjfi?hl=en

Comment: Sorry to tell, but all of your links are rotten.